# AngularJs orderBy Sorting String should be less than numeric ( n/a, 0 , 1 , 2 ,5 ,100)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I'm running angularjs filter sorting on table,

when i get value that equal to numeric 'n/a' for example the sorting is not correct

string should be less than numeric i would expect the order to be n/a, 0 , 1 , 2 ,5 ,100

but the order is 0 , 1 , 2 ,5 ,100, n/a which is not correct,

i also attach an image and the sorting code,

if you have any idea how to solve it please do

thanks.

here is example link to [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liad/3cunf/)

http://jsfiddle.net/liad/3cunf/

the example code is:

```
<div ng-click="orderByField='rating'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
```

[image]

Comment: what you mean n/a ???? Is it undefined value?

Comment: This is just a JavaScript sort.  By default, if the content of the array is mixed, JS will convert to string and then do a sort.  So, it looks to me like it is correct.  You may have to implement your own ordering.

Comment: n/a is a value it's not undefined it is string coming from the serve,r i didn't implemented it by myself i just use order by field orderByField i attached js fiddle @DavinTryon

Comment: Exactly.  So, when JS does a `sort()` it will be sorted to the bottom.  `n` is after `1`.

Comment: i understand ok let me check that out

Comment: @DavinTryon do you have a suggestion of changing orderByField to do javascript sort or how should i impliment that kind of sorting?

Comment: can i use "expression" maybe to solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure.  But `orderBy` with expression looks like a good way to go.  Expression should be able to be a controller function.

Answer (score 0):

This solve my issue

```
 /*
 orderObjectBy - netural filter of string and numbers
 */
.filter('orderObjectBy', [function() {
    return function(items, field, reverse) {
        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
            filtered.push(item);
        });
        filtered.sort(function (a, b) {

            var result =  (a[field] - b[field]);
            if (isNaN(result)) {

                if (a[field] == 'n/a' && b[field] != 'n/a')
                {
                    return -1;
                }
                else if (a[field] != 'n/a' && b[field] == 'n/a')
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            return result;


        });
        if(reverse) filtered.reverse();
        return filtered;
    };
}]
```